# Why is this new CSS manifest file not being compiled during Heroku slug compilation, while the normal application manifest works fine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.2.11 running on the Heroku Cedar stack. I don't compile assets locally, they are compiled automatically during slug compilation, as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar#compiling-assets-during-slug-compilation). I have just created a new CSS manifest file `app/assets/stylesheets/new_manifest.css.scss` in addition to the default `application.css.scss`. When I push to Heroku, this manifest file is not getting compiled like `application.css.scss` is. The new manifest file works fine in development. Why would that be happening?

**application.rb**

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

**production.rb**

```
config.assets.compile = false
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

**Console output from Heroku push**

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (83.62s)
```

**Sample page**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "new_manifest", media: "all" %>
```

Comment: I think you should keep the manifest files with prefix `css` , not `css.scss` . Anyway , how do you include the `new_manifest.css.scss` in `aplication.css`? Could you post your `application.css.scss` ?

Comment: @QumaraSixOneTour I've edited the question to show how I include the new manifest. It's not included in application.css.scss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to add `config.assets.precompile += %w( new_manifest.css )` to production.rb, as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets). This isn't required in development, but is required in production, which caused my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you say your `new_manifest` is a manifest file , it should be included in the main manifest for the application : `application.css` . In case you are including it by `stylesheet_link_tag` it is not under asset-pipeline control (it is treated like a pure CSS file , not as a manifest one). It is about to be precompiled also , but inclusions are about to be ignored . There is a more proper way to include additional manifest files into the main `application.css` : [index files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)(look for 2.1.2 ) .